# redstone ore minecraft pocket edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On Mine craft pocket edition I found Red stone ore deep down in the earth world thing. I can't mine it. I tried using a stone pickax on it , and it took around one minute to break and when it did I couldn't collect it BTW it's Minecraft pocket edition on kindle fire and it's version 7.00.

Comment: I agree with @Ullallulloo

Answer (score 0):

Redstone requires at least an iron pick to mine successfully.

Comment: Wrong game edition.

Comment: It will apply when they add redstone dust to PE though.